# Lottery Program Java Compare two numbers

Tags: java, numbers, compare, treeset

So basically I'm writing a lottery program using two tree sets each with 6 integers, one user inputted and another random generated. I have to compare the numbers to each other to output a prize, for example if two numbers were to match then you win 100 dollars. I'm having trouble on how to create such a method. Any help would be great thanks!

Here is my main,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Set<Integer>s1 = createWinningNumber();
    Set<Integer>s2 = getUserNumber();

    System.out.println("Your ticket was: "+s2);
    System.out.println("Winning numbers: "+s1);

}//End of main
public static Set<Integer> getUserNumber()
{
    int set = 0;
    Set<Integer> number = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Pick your Lucky Lotto Numbers");
    System.out.print("Type 6 lotto numbers: ");
    for(int i = 0; i< 6;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("");
        set = keyboard.nextInt();
        number.add(set);
    }
    return number;  
}//End of getUserNumber

public static Set<Integer> createWinningNumber()
{
    Set<Integer> winning = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    Random generator = new Random();
    for(int i = 0;i<6;i++)
    {
        winning.add(generator.nextInt(40));
    }
    return winning;
}//End of createWinningNumber
```

Output so far

```
Pick your Lucky Lotto Numbers
Type 6 lotto numbers: 4 12 7 35 20 1
Your ticket was: [1, 4, 7, 12, 20, 35]
Winning numbers: [5, 8, 19, 24, 32]
```

Comment: You forgot to post the relevant code parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set`s are the way to go. Good choice.

The operation you're looking for is the *intersection* of two sets. In Java, this is implemented as:

```
s1.retainAll(s2);
```

`s1` will now contain only elements that are *also* in `s2`.

You can then use `s1.size()` to count the number of common numbers:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Set<Integer>s1 = createWinningNumber();
    Set<Integer>s2 = getUserNumber();

    System.out.println("Your ticket was: "+s2);
    System.out.println("Winning numbers: "+s1);

    s1.retainAll(s2); // s1 contains the intersection of previous s1 and s2
    System.out.println("You had " + s1.size() +
      " numbers in common with the winning number.");
}
```

**EDIT:** If you want to keep the original sets, try this:

```
Set<Integer> s3 = new Set<Integer>(s1); // copy s1
s3.retainAll(s2);
```

Comment: One thing to note about `Set.retainAll(Collection)` is that it can modify the collection you are calling retainAll on. So unless all the numbers in `s1` is contained in `s2` then after the call to retainAll in your example, `s1` would no longer contain the same values.

Comment: @EmilH: Exactly, that's the point: we only want the values that are contained in both sets. Then, we count to see how many were *retained*.

Comment: Yeah, just pointing out the obvious I suppose :) It's not an issue here, but suppose you changed the method in your example to do the System.out.println last, then the output of the program would be different.

Comment: So I did the method you suggested and everything works great, however I'm not sure why but the createWinningNumber set has decreased by one for example instead of outputting six numbers it outputs            [0, 2, 4, 5, 9]

Comment: It only contains five numbers because those were the only numbers in common. See my edit for how to keep the original sets.

Comment: I get what you're trying to do but its still not working. I'll try to do the rest on my own. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Set.containsAll(Collection)` [link to API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29) to check if one set is contained in the other. Then you could check that the sized match and if so you have a winner:

```
s1.containsAll(s2) && s2.size().equals(s1.size())
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
s1.containsAll(s2) && s2.containsAll(s1)
```

To check if the two sets are subsets of each other (and therefore contains only the same elements). If you need to know how many matches are in common then you could do what WChargin illustrated. I would perhaps create a new Set containing the common numbers by doing something like:

```
Set<Integer> commonNumbers = new TreeSet<Integer>(s1);
commonNumbers.retainAll(s2);
```

That way I don't modify the original `s1` collection.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cheap resolution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> wins = new HashSet<Integer>();

        Set<Integer> winners = createWinningNumber();
        Set<Integer> numbers = getUserNumber();

        for(Integer winner : winners) {
            for(Integer number : numbers) {
                if(winner == number) {
                    wins.add(number);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Your ticket was: " + numbers);
        System.out.println("Winning numbers: " + winners);
        System.out.println("Your Winning numbers: " + wins);

    }
```